# Spring Boot Active Directory Authentication Not Redirecting After Succesful Login

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to create a web page accessible through active directory authentication. I successfully connect and can authenticate credentials. When an incorrect log in is submitted the terminal prints: `Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid`. Nothing prints in the terminal on correct credentials.

The problem is after I 'successfully' log in the web page is not shown. Instead, the log in window continually shows up and does not redirect. How do I get to the web page after credentials are authenticated? Below is the code I'm using.

#### ADConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ADConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ad_domain}")
    private String AD_DOMAIN;

    @Value("${ad_url}")
    private String AD_URL;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL);
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    }
}
```

#### Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "home page";
   }
}
```

#### App.java

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```